Change locale LC_NUMERIC decimal_point for shell or individual command
In my bash environment (version 5.2.26), the only available locale is French, which is normally fine. But like most people in France, it is regularly necessary to handle floating point numbers with a radix character . instead of , from the French locale. Is there a way to temporarily change just this one attribute decimal_point of LC_NUMERIC, without installing or creating any locales? It would be equally useful to have a solution either for an entire bash session or just for an individual command (for example sort -g).
It doesn't work well to change the entire locale, for example LC_ALL=C, because that will change datetime formats, which really need to remain in the French locale at all times. What I'm looking for is a way to change exactly the decimal_point of LC_NUMERIC and nothing else related to the locale.


As somebody(?)
pointed out, you should probably have the “C” or “POSIX” locale
on even a minimal system. 
So, as you probably understand, you should be able to say
LC_NUMERIC=C

or
LC_NUMERIC=POSIX

(you may also need export LC_NUMERIC) 
to set that part of the locale for an entire bash session. 
If you wanted to make that permanent,
you would add those commands to your .login.

As waltinator says,
you can set environment variable(s) for a single command:

LC_NUMERIC=C yourcommand

Or use LC_NUMERIC=POSIX.

It may not have been clear from that answer
that you can set environment variable(s) for each simple command. 
So you could doLC_NUMERIC=C command1  |  LC_NUMERIC=C command2

But I doubt that cat is affected by locale;
cat file.csv | LC_NUMERIC=C sort -t',' -k3 -n

should be good enough. 
(And, strictly speaking, you don’t need actually the quotes;
you can say “-t,”. 
But feel free to use quotes
if you believe that they make the command clearer.)

But don’t even do cat file | …;
just Google “UUOC” and do
LC_NUMERIC=C sort -t',' -k3 -n file.csv

(specifying the input file as an argument on the sort command) or
LC_NUMERIC=C sort -t',' -k3 -n < file.csv

(specifying the input file with I/O redirection).





sort -nt, -k3 is part of the problem here as that specifies the sort key as being the portion of the line starting with the 3rd comma-separated field. With sort -nt, -k3,3, you'd be sorting on the 3rd field only which would then be guaranteed not to contain a , (which could be considered as decimal radix character or thousand separator depending on locale).

You can set environment variables for a single command:
LC_ALL=C yourcommand


This works, but what if I have pipes? For example, sort doesn't work here: LC_ALL=C cat file.csv | sort -t',' -k3 -n. Also, setting LC_ALL is not ideal because it changes date formats and everything else. What I need is to change exactly the decimal_point and nothing else. This appears to have fallen outside of the environment design entirely, although people all over the world are regularly using . for the radix character in formal and/or international work.

(1) So try LC_NUMERIC=C (or LC_NUMERIC=POSIX) instead of LC_ALL.   (2) You can set environment variable(s) for each simple command.  So you could do LC_NUMERIC=C command₁ | LC_NUMERIC=C command₂.  (3a) But I doubt that cat is affected by locale; cat file.csv | LC_NUMERIC=C sort -t',' -k3 -n should be good enough.  (3b) But don’t even do cat  file | …; just Google “UUOC” and do LC_NUMERIC=C sort -t',' -k3 -n file.csv.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' nice, that works, didn't know the pipe would allow that. Make it an answer if you want credit.
